# How to check a PNG for grayscale/alpha color type?

Tags: php, png, gd

PHP and GD seem to have trouble creating images from PNGs of type greyscale with alpha when using `imagecreatefrompng()`. The results are incredibly distorted.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to test for the colour type in order to notify the user of the incompatibility?

Example:

Original Image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/246391/Robin.png
Resulting Image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/246391/Robin_result.png

Code:

```
<?php

$resource = imagecreatefrompng('./Robin.png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($resource);
imagedestroy($resource);
```

Cheers,

Aron

Comment: What do you mean by distorted?
There are certain steps you need to take to preserve alpha transparency.

But greyscale issues... that's new to me

Comment: I've updated my example to include an example image. Preserving alpha transparency is fine. It's specifically greyscale images with transparency that GD can't handle, see haim evgi's answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The colour type of a PNG image is stored at byte offset 25 in the file (counting from 0).  So if you can get hold of the actual bytes of the PNG file, simply look at byte 25 (I don't do PHP, so I don't know how to do that):

- 0 - greyscale
- 2 - RGB
- 3 - RGB with palette
- 4 - greyscale + alpha
- 6 - RGB + alpha

The preceding byte (offset 24) gives the number of bits per channel.  See [the PNG spec](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html) for more details.

In a slight twist a PNG file may have "1-bit alpha" (like GIFs) by having a tRNS chunk (when it is colour type 0 2 or 3).

Answer (score 5):

i landed here today searching for a way to tell (via php) if a specific .png image is an alpha-png one -
David Jones' answer points to the right direction, really easy to implement in php:

**file_get_contents** to load just that 25' byte (there it is, indeed!), and
**ord()** to get its ASCII value, to test it (against '6' in my case)

```
if(ord(file_get_contents($alpha_png_candidate, NULL, NULL, 25, 1)) == 6) {
  is_alpha_png_so_do_something();
  }
```

actually i needed that for assuring backward compatibility with ie6 
within cms-user-generated-pages, to replace all **alpha-png < img > tags** with  **inline-block < spans >** - the alpha-png file will then be served as variable for the  **ms-proprietary css property *filter***

```
.alpha_png_span{
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='$alpha_png_candidate', sizingMethod='crop')
  }
```

...and it all works, so thanks!

paolo

Comment: Using `(bool) (ord(file_get_contents($alpha_png_candidate, NULL, NULL, 25, 1)) & 4)` instead will tell you if there's an alpha channel regardless of whether the image is greyscale or rgb.

Answer (score 0):

see this answer 
:

Another usefull note for those using ImageCreateFromPng:
PHP and GD do not recognize grayscale/alpha images.

**So if you use grayscale images with transparency between 0% and 100%, then save the image as RGB.**

At least this is true for PHP Version 4.4.2-1 and in 5.1.2-1 with pictures made with GIMP 2.2.8.

url :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

Comment: Thanks, however I'm looking for a way of detecting that the image is greyscale with transparency before trying to create the resource with `imagecreatefrompng()`.

The images are submitted to the site so unfortunately I have no way of re-saving the image as RBG (at least I'm not aware of a method).