# Create a true grayscale PNG in PHP

Tags: php, png, rgb, grayscale, gdlib

I need to create a grayscale image in PHP. I am not talking about an indexed image with grayscale values in its palette, but about a TRUE grayscale image. The difference is in the 26th byte of the PNG (color type):

```
0 - greyscale  <-- THIS IS WHAT I NEED
2 - RGB
3 - RGB with palette
4 - greyscale + alpha
6 - RGB + alpha
```

(See [How to check a PNG for grayscale/alpha color type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057923/how-to-check-a-png-for-grayscale-alpha-color-type) for details)

I tried `imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);` as well as `imagetruecolortopalette($im, false, 255);` but all I get are either RGB grayscale images (color type 2) or RGB palette images with a grayscale palette (color type 3). I also tried to initialize the image with `imagecreate()` instead of `imagecreatetruecolor()` but again this only leads to a palette image.

Is there any way to create a color type 0 grayscale PNG with PHP's GD functions (or any other functions in PHP)?

Here are some samples of different grayscale images to show what I mean. They all look the same, but if you open them in PhotoShop and look at the Image -> Mode setting, you see the difference. Also a hex editor will reveal the difference in the 26th byte:

[image: RGB] RGB, **color type 2**, 3149 bytes
[image: RGB palette] RGB palette, **color type 3**, 3971 bytes
[image: True Grayscale Image] True grayscale image, **color type 0**, 1105 bytes <-- THIS IS WHAT I NEED

**UPDATE 01:**

Here is the basic code that I use to create the PNGs. Commented lines are alternatives that I have tried:

```
//$im = imagecreate($image_size, $image_size);
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($image_size, $image_size);

//imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
//imagetruecolortopalette($im, false, 255);

imagepng($im, $imgPathName);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: how does your code look so far?

Comment: @Breezer: See "UPDATE 01" in my OP.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php
I think this tutorial will help  you along the way, http://php.about.com/od/gdlibrary/ss/grayscale_gd.htm

Comment: with imagecolorallocate you define what colors is to be used, the palette basically

Comment: Sorry Breezer, but you are way off. As I clearly stated I do NOT want to create a palette image, but an 8-bit grayscale image. It has nothing to do with palettes. It is similar to an RGB image but with only one color channel instead of three channels.

Comment: hmmm perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorset.php?

Comment: Breezer, if you read the word "palette" in any of your researches, just drop it. I have read this all. As said: My problem has nothing to do with palettes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GD library does not support converting to a "true" grayscale.  It only supports RGB and TrueColor*.

> Is there any way to create a color type 0 grayscale PNG with PHP's GD functions (or any other functions in PHP)?

[ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) is what you are looking for.

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage('file.png');
$im->setImageType(Imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE);
$im->writeImage('file.gray.png');
```

Comment: @Xeoncross from the source https://bitbucket.org/pierrejoye/gd-libgd/src - only supports RGB and TrueColor* output.

Comment: @h0tw1r3: That's it - thank you! As a side note: I have sworn to never use ImageMagick again as long as I have access to GraphicsMagick on the target machine. Fortunately h0tw1r3's code will work perfectly with GM, if you replace ``Imagick`` by ``Gmagick`` (and install the GraphicsMagick PHP extension).

Comment: I found that the Gmagick and Imagick PHP extensions are extremely hard to find as precompiled Windows versions. So just in case any reader of this thread will look for a Windows solution: Better use a shell call to IM/GM executables like this: ``exec('gm mogrify -type grayscale "C:/path/to/your/file.png"');``